# Obtener un dato de una tabla de una base de datos Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hola que tal tengo un pequeño problema, el motivo es que quiero solo obtener un dato de una tabla de una base de datos para imprimirlo en mi vista. El dato que obtengo lo llamo desde mi controlador:

Controlador (EJM):

```
$dato2 = Tabla::CargarDatos_con_JOIN(2)->select('Columna.Codigo')->get();
return view('Vista.create', compact('dato2);
```

El numero 2 que envio en el metodo es porque estoy haciendo un join y eso no tiene nada que ver .Luego al momento lo pego en un input de mi vista:

Vista (EJM):

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label>Código:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo" value="{{$dato2}}">
</div>
```

Luego al momento de cargar mi vista viene el problema, en vez que por ejemplo me cargue en el input:
'273', me carga asi: [{"Codigo":"273"}]
 Saben como borrar el [], {} y el nombre de la columna "Codigo":, para que sólo me salga el 273 ?
O estoy llamando mal el dato seleccionado??
PD: El metodo CargarDatos_con_JOIN(2) lo uso en varios lados, asi que solo quiero sacar un dato de ese metodo en vez de crear otro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de varias formas, voy a explicar dos de estas:

1. Con el método pluck aplicado a la colección obtienes un array con los valores que solicitas, y posteriormente seleccionas el primer (único) elemento:

   ```
   $dato2->pluck('Codigo')[0]
   ```
2. Utilizar first en vez de get (para obtener solo un elemento) y obtienes el valor respectivo:

   ```
   $dato2 = Tabla::CargarDatos_con_JOIN(2)->select('Columna.Codigo')->first();

   return view('Vista.create', ['dato2' => $dato2->Codigo];
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo! Me sirvió! (y)

Comment: amigo disculpa una pregunta..esto ['dato2' => $dato2->Codigo] si lo quiero poner al compact se puede? Lo que pasa es que, estoy que lo valido con el request y por ejemplo al momento de querer mandar el dato a otro lado y si un caso no escribo nada en vez que salga el error que hace el request, sale igual "Trying to get property of non-object" como puedo hacer?

Comment: Parece que hay un error en tu lógica, aunque no entiendo bien lo que dices hacer, la validación no debería tener ningún inconveniente.

Comment: Todo el formulario esta valido con request, cada input tiene un old(), po ejemplo si completo todos los datos, se envian normal los datos pero si un caso no completo algun input del formulario me tendria que salir un error del request {!!$errors->first('servicio', '<span class=error>:message</span>')!!} y los demas tendrian que estar con el old() pero en vez que salga eso sale "Trying to get property of non-object"